# Android SDK cannot resolve Twilio dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, twilio, twilio-programmable-voice

I'm trying to setup boilerplate [Twilio Voice Quickstart for Android](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android#quickstart). But I guess there is smth wrong with my gradle file. Android SDK cannot resolve all twilio packets and koushikdutta packets.

***Twilio packets:***

[image]

***Gradle app:***

```html
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

}
```

***Gradle project:***

```html
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
}
```

Is it gradle file problem or what's going on here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So problem was fixed in a very wierd way:
1) I decreased packet's versions by 1 in Gradle file.
'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.7' -> 'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.6'
'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8' -> 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7'
2) Gradly Synch
3) The packets imported correctly
4) Increased version of files back to up-to-date version
'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.6' -> 'com.twilio:voice-android:2.0.6'
'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.7' -> 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.8'
5) Gradly Synch
It works! No idea why)